# Angular 2 chain route params and http subscriptions

Tags: http, angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to get route params and then get data from the service

```
 this.route.params
   .switchMap(params => this.service.getData(params['id']))
   .subscribe(value => this.value = value,
     error => console.log(error));
```

This works fine, until first error. After the error this line doesn't calls no more `params => this.noteService.GetParams(params['id'])`.

I can write something like this, but i think there is a better way

```
  this.route.params.subscribe(
    params => {
      this.service.getData(params['id']).subscribe(
        result => console.log(result),
        error => console.log(error))
  });
```

My service

```
public getData(id): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('api/data/' + id)
    .map(data => data.json())
    .catch(error => Observable.throw(error));
 }
```

**Update** 
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32750605/2156149) helped me a lot to understand what is going on.
When I call `Observable.throw(error)` subscription to route params stops with an error. So instead of throwing error I just need to return empty observable.

**my.component.ts**

```
this.route.params
  .switchMap(params => this.service.GetData(params['id']))
  .subscribe(result => {
    if (result) this.data = result; 
    else console.log('error');
  });
```

**my.service.ts**

```
public GetData(id): Observable<any> {
   let url = 'api/data' + id;
   return this.http.get(url)
    .map(data => data.json())
    .catch(error => Observable.of(null));
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: 504 (Gateway Timeout)

Answer (score 1):

I'm building a github users application right now and had the same problem.
Here is a solution that works for me:

**users.service.ts**

```
public getByUsername(username: string): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.http
            .get(`${this.url}/${username}`)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
```

**user.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.route.params
            .flatMap((v: any, index: number) => {
                return this.usersService.getByUsername(v.name);
            })
            .subscribe(data => this.user = data);
    }
```

So, basically the [flatMap operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) does the trick.
Here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268482/chaining-rxjs-observables-from-http-data-in-angular2-with-typescript) to another question,
helping me to figure out how things work with chaining RxJS Observables